# why multiple ng-select options doesn't work?

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to do this example with multiple choices https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts but it doesn't work for me. I don't know what's happening...

This is my code:

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <label htmlFor="ca" class="sr-only"> Asignaturas:</label>
    <ng-select [items]="asignaturasLista"
    bindLabel="name"
    bindValue="id"
    [multiple]="true"
    placeholder="Select asignaturas"
    [(ngModel)]="asignaturas"> 
    </ng-select>
    
  </div>

  Selected asignaturas: {{asignaturas}}
```

It doesn't show anything on sleected asignaturas

I have this on my component:

```
      asignaturasLista  = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Álgebra'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Física'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Inglés'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Matemáticas'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Lenguaje'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Historia'}
];

  asignaturas: string[];
```

Comment: Did you install ng-select? Did you import NgSelectModule and FormsModule into your AppModule?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is not working for you.

I implanted your template and code to that stack blitz example you gave and it seems to work:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-r8tcq8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question.